# Looking for driver solution for Realtek RTL8821CE Wireless Network Adapter for HP

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I'm a brand new Ubuntu user. Installed it on a new HP 14-dk0024. I'm getting "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" and have been looking for solutions. I have disabled secure boot. I'm new to using a terminal and have tried some of the previously stated solutions but haven't had success. Are there updated drivers that I can install and how do I do that. Thank you!

Comment: Look at this: https://medium.com/@kimiyukiyukawa/installing-rtl8821ce-network-controller-on-ubuntu-335d8ccb8a92

Comment: Thank you. I did try this more than once. Wi-Fi still not working. I'm at a loss. I don't understand this stuff fully but doing my best to follow instructions an input correct commands.

Comment: When you installed ubuntu did you marked(activated) the option of allow 3rd party drivers?(such as wifi,sound,etc) Maybe the problem is there(look if you have "disable secure boot")

Comment: Thank you Munsko for checking. I did both of those things. And I've tried several posted fixes including on here and youtube. I'm completely new to Ubuntu and to using the terminal, but I've done my best to follow all instructions exactly. I'm hoping that there isn't some incompatibility issue with the computer I bought.

Comment: One thing more have come to me: try to check the kernel version that you have in the ubuntu 18.04 and the kernel versions that is supported by your wireless adapter: sometimes you dont have the right kernel version, so you SO(your kernel) didnt recognize the driver. PD: I found this,maybe it helps https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=290073

Comment: PD2: if you found that your kernel version isnt compatible with you card, you can change it(i dont know how, but i know that is possible) and if it doesnt solves the problem you could try another Ubuntu distro(like Lubuntu or Xubuntu) that may can have a compatible version(im not really sure of the last thing), but dont give up on linux :)

Comment: I ran the commands from the linuxmint forum post above. I have run them before though. So didn't work. I tells me I already have that kernel and that the dkms install is complete.

Comment: @Munsko Thank you for encouraging me to keep at it! Somehow after another reboot it is working! I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem! if you remember what you have done before the reboot, try to add that as solution, so if someone elsa have your problem will have the solution also :)